# Move the pointer with the head on android

Tags: mouse

Allow me to introduce myself, my name is Stéphane, I am quadriplegic.

I am running this topic because I need help.

My disability means that I cannot use my arms. I'm looking for a system where I can move the mouse cursor with my head on an android tablet.

I found a system with [OpenCv](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dbJvwXaWFdY) but it's on Windows Would it be possible to do the same on android ?

Comment: This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sesame.phone_nougat) claims to do this. It has a good rating too. You may like to test it

Comment: I tried but it is not very reliable